# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_formsmain'

Tags: python, django, ajax, paytm

Please help me as I am new to Django and I am learning out of my curiosity. I tried to find the solution but couldn't. I have spent 2 days to find the appropriate solution. Please help.

I cloned the repository from github and it gives me the error as follows:

```
    (env) C:\Users\Tenzin Karma\Desktop\critique\Wrappers-India-Online-master>python manage.py runserver
    Watching for file changes with StatReloader
    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File `"C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 892, in run`
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Tenzin Karma\Desktop\critique\Wrappers-India-Online-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Tenzin Karma\Desktop\critique\Wrappers-India-Online-master\env\lib\site-`packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_runautoreload.raise_last_exception()`
  

File "C:\Users\Tenzin Karma\Desktop\critique\Wrappers-India-Online-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]

      File "C:\Users\Tenzin Karma\Desktop\critique\Wrappers-India-Online-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
        autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
      File "C:\Users\Tenzin Karma\Desktop\critique\Wrappers-India-Online-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Tenzin Karma\Desktop\critique\Wrappers-India-Online-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "C:\Users\Tenzin Karma\Desktop\critique\Wrappers-India-Online-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
        app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
      File "C:\Users\Tenzin Karma\Desktop\critique\Wrappers-India-Online-master\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 224, in create
        import_module(entry)
      File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_formsmain'
```

Comment: What repository did you clone? It looks like it's broken.

Comment: You might be missing commas in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list (check `settings.py`).

Comment: Can you show the settings.py file, INSTALLED APPS section?

Comment: looks like typo should be `crispy_forms`  in settings.py INSTALLED_APPS section.

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms'
    'main',
    'saler',
    'coupon',
    'corsheaders',

]

Comment: Thank you sir...@AKX.....Akash...ItsMilann.. for your responses.. I got it.. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error , it looks like you are missing the module. You can try

```
pip install django-crispy-forms
```

Also from the error logs , I can see you are using virtual env, please make sure you install the package in the same venv.

Once installed, if it still shows the error , then
in settings.py installed apps add crispy_forms In settings.py add CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4

Comment: yes sir... i already did and this was the error i was facing.

Comment: wow... i reinstalled the project and it gave some error... pip install django-crispy-forms worked.. thank you so much sir... got inspired to continue..